# macOS Terminal doesn't paste correctly

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave

Recently after upgrading to macOS Mojave, my workflow has been seriously impacted by the inability for macOS Terminal to be able to ***paste the contents of my clipboard correctly***.

When I paste contents, the letters in my clipboard become garbled and are pasted out of order of their actual text

this was in my clipboard as `doc_header.to_html` and came out like this when I pasted it

[image]

this was in my clipboard as `doc_header`

[image]

I have been a Mac OS user since the 1980s and I have developed code on Mac OS since 2001.  With problems & bugs like these it makes me seriously wonder if macOS continues to be a viable platform for developing software in the future.

video is here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsIFj.jpg

this is Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6
running on MacBook Air Early 2015 2.2 Ghz Core i7
with 8GB of ram

Comment: Please clarify these questions: 1. Is that macOS' built-in Terminal.app? 2. What shell are you using? 3. Have you tested if the problem happens when you start that shell without the dotfiles/configuration?

Comment: Also where do copy it from?

Comment: either out of my code editor RubyMine or from somewhere else in the terminal itself. However, when the symptom demonstrates itself, I am able to re-paste the text into a plain text file in TextEdit without problems so I suspect the Terminal is somehow interpreting the paste and re-typing the characters one-by-one.

Comment: You'll note that the behavior is completely inconsistent, the characters don't even re-paste in a garbled fashion, they re-paste in different garbled ways at different times. this indicates to me it is some kind of terminal emulating the keystrokes character by character and coming up against race conditions in the operating system

Comment: @theonlygusti 1-- yes it is macOS built-in Terminal. 2-- I think it is just bash shell.

Comment: @theonlygusti -- as far as your third question, I wouldn't really be able to run Ruby or Node without node package manager or ruby version manager, but I could try to strip away everything else.

Comment: I suppose I should have clarified that I saw the problem only while using the Ruby debugger, specifically inside of a Rails console.

Comment: @JasonFB which program exactly are you inside of in the terminal when you get this problem?

Comment: it's the rails console, executed with `bundle exec rails console`

Comment: Stock question any time I see weird behavior post-upgrade from a long-time macOS user: Have you tried this in a clean user profile? Make a new user, try the same copy-paste. Some weird bugs are the result of years of cruft in your profile. If you don't see this behavior in a clean profile on the same machine, you may have to rebuild your user profile. I can say with 100% confidence that this is NOT how Mojave normally acts, I am in Terminal all the time and nothing is pasting weirdly like this.